# How to destroy a ADMOB ad

Tags: lua, admob, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

when i use the underneath code in my main.lua file it displays the ad as i want it to be.
but when i add  **"ads.hide()"** *(the ad stay on every scene)*  in the **"exitScene"** scene section i get this error in the terminal " attempt to index global 'ads' (a nil value)" which i understand as the ads don't display in the simulator but when i open the app op my phone (galaxy s4) non of the buttons respond, and it just stay on the main.lua file/scene

```
local provider = "admob"
local appID = "**********"
local ads = require "ads"

local screenGroup = self.view
local statusText = display.newText( "", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 22 )
statusText:setTextColor( 255 )
statusText:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
statusText.x, statusText.y = display.contentWidth * 0.5, 160

local showAd
local function adListener( event )

    local msg = event.response
    print("Message received from the ads library: ", msg)

    if event.isError then
        statusText:setTextColor( 255, 0, 0 )
        statusText.text = "Error Loading Ad"
        statusText.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
        local screenGroup = self.view
        showAd( "banner" )
    else

    end
end

if appID then
    ads.init( provider, appID, adListener )
end

local sysModel = system.getInfo("model")
local sysEnv = system.getInfo("environment")

    showAd = function( adType )
    local screenGroup = self.view
    local adX, adY = display.screenOriginX, 400
    statusText.text = ""
    ads.show( adType, { x=adX, y=adY } )
end

if sysEnv == "simulator" then
else
local screenGroup = self.view
    showAd( "banner" )
end
```

Hi how can i close or destroy a "admob" ad on screen change ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to require **ads** in every scene you create

Add this line to every Lua file that are using the **ads plugin**

```
local ads = require("ads")
```

Comment: i got a ad on the 'home.lua' and dont want the add on the 'games.lua'....if i add 'local ads = require("ads")' to 'game.lua' the ad is still on screen

Comment: You need it to use ads.hide()

Answer (score 0):

```
ads.hide( )
ads:removeSelf()
ads=nil
```

you can insert above into any event listener or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this function in every screen.

if ads then

ads.hide()

end

Note: When you are generating dynamic ads then there are time duration between the ads.
So if the ads is on the screen it will hide otherwise not.
But when you not check the if condition and move to next scene the ads will load again.